# JavaFX Button for FileInputStream?

Tags: java, file, javafx, fileinputstream

```
 runEncrypt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                File inputFile = new File("/Users/aktasberk/Desktop/hey");
                File encryptedFile = new File("/Users/aktasberk/Desktop/Encrypted_"+inputFile.getName());
                File decryptedFile = new File("/Users/aktasberk/Desktop/Decrypted_"+inputFile.getName());

                try {
                    String key = "16BitKeyIsHere16";
                CryptoUtils.encrypt(key, inputFile, encryptedFile);
                  CryptoUtils.decrypt(key, encryptedFile, decryptedFile);
                } catch (CryptoException ex) {
                  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
```

Okay so I have an encryption&decryption project, the encrypting and decrypting works fine but I have some problems using FileInputStream to get the file from directory, I have a browse button to do that but could not make it work, so as you can see in the code I get the input file manually.

Below here is my browse button opening up a file dialog to let me choose a file.

```
browseEncrypt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


            File selectedFile = chooseEncrypt.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if (selectedFile != null) {
                encryptPath.setText(selectedFile.getPath());
                primaryStage.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I need to get the file from browse button instead of declaring it manually in the code, I can be more specific if info is needed, thanks.

Comment: Should the runEncrypt button become an inner action of browse button to use the selectedFile as a path? This just came into my mind

Comment: So the `browseEncrypt.setOnAction` is not working?

Comment: Why is `primaryStage.show()` there?

Comment: Did you try using a field to store the value???

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Yeah was nonsense, I removed it now it didn't affect thanks. It is now working I merged these two button codes somehow and it is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete local:

```
File encryptedFile = new File("/Users/aktasberk/Desktop/Encrypted_"+inputFile.getName());
```

Make global

```
File encryptedFile;
```

Then:

```
browseEncrypt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


        File selectedFile = chooseEncrypt.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        if (selectedFile != null) {
            encryptPath.setText(selectedFile.getPath());
            encryptedFile = selectedFile;//Add This!
            primaryStage.show();//Not sure why this is here?
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I declared it global now instead of that. Working perfectly.